# Usage of Commit Statement

Tags: oracle, commit

How do I use the Commit statement correctly? Do I have to use commit statement for every insert statement and every function? For example, if I alter a table to add a column do I have to use a commit statement?

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Please tag only relevant RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a [DDL statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm) (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `GRANT`, etc) then:

> Oracle Database implicitly commits the current transaction before and after every DDL statement.

If you run a DML statement (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`, `CALL`, `MERGE`) then:

> These statements do not implicitly commit the current transaction.

and you will need to manually commit the uncommitted transactions (but you do not have to `COMMIT` after every statement).

If you want to perform a partial rollback then you can use [`SAVEPOINT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/transact.htm#CNCPT1121)s.

You should not put `COMMIT` statements in functions or procedures so that you can use multiple functions/procedures in a single transaction and then `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` that entire transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Commits are needed when you change data in your tables (insert, update and delete). As long as you do not commit, other users will not see the changed data and you still have the option to undo the changes by executing a rollback.

There is no need to commit after every single statement.

Commits are not needed when changing the table itself (alter table). In fact, the alter table statement issues an implicit commit.

[Some more on implicit/explicit commit statements in Oracle](http://www.acehints.com/2011/07/explicit-vs-implicit-commit-in-oracle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on accumulated experience and "good practices" - you should not implement "commit" statements in your functions/procedures (most of the time, depends on the task, what are you try to achieve). The "commit" decision should lie on the user, who invokes your function/procedures.
What you can implement, is a "rollback", when exceptions are occurred/caught.
Often, when stored procedures or function are invoked from the application/web part, they are auto-committed (the option can be changed within transaction methods, as far i know, at least in java).

Answer (score -1):

try like that:

```
 try {
        // First of all, let's begin a transaction
        $db->beginTransaction();

        // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
        $db->query('first query');
        $db->query('second query');
        $db->query('third query');

        // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
        // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
        $db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // An exception has been thrown
        // We must rollback the transaction
        $db->rollback();
    }
```

Comment: For a **query** a COMMIT or ROLLBACK is useless (even though a SELECT begins also a transaction, at least in Oracle). Your example does not make much sense because an unhandled exception performs a ROLLBACK anyway.